# Import classic script and module in web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to work with web workers and I need to be able to import dynamically classic scripts and also modules scripts. So I need to do something like this:

```
new Worker("worker1.js", { type: "module" });
```

In my worker :

```
importScripts('/scripts/classic.js');
import('/scripts/module.js').then((module) => {
    // Something
});
```

The problem is that it seems impossible to use importScripts in a module worker since I get the following error: **Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Module scripts don't support importScripts()**

Would there be a solution to do what I want or I am forced to choose between importing classic scripts or importing modules scripts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, from a module Worker the `importScripts()` method is not available.
It is indeed expected that when you are in a module script, all your dependencies will adhere to ESM too.

However it's quite surprising to see that the code you do use would actually work, **in a classic worker**.
There, the dynamic `import()` method will be available, along with the traditional `importScripts()` one:

```js
const makeScriptURL = (content) => {
  const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/javascript" });
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

const moduleScriptURL = makeScriptURL(`
  export const foo = "bar";
`);

const defaultScriptURL = makeScriptURL(`
  self.bar = "baz";
`);

const workerURL = makeScriptURL(`
  importScripts("${defaultScriptURL}");
    import("${moduleScriptURL}")
      .then(({foo}) => postMessage({foo, bar}))
      .catch((err) => postMessage(err.message));
`);

const worker = new Worker(workerURL);
worker.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(data);
worker.onerror = (evt) => console.error(evt.message);
```

However note that the browser support for dynamic `import()` in a classic Worker is the same as module Worker support (i.e no Firefox yet).

Comment: Well seen, I thought that dynamic imports needed to be in a module but no. And it doesn't seem to work only for workers but also for scripts imported from html without the module type as long as they are not static imports.

Comment: It seems support for module workers was added to Firefox recently, in 114 (https://caniuse.com/?search=module%20worker). The support for dynamic imports in workers is also available since 114 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)